# How to deserialize JSON using GSON to an object of different field

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I receive this object from the API, I want to deserialize it with GSON:

```
{
results: {
 clothing_items: [
  {
    id: 422,
    created_at: "2020-01-20 11:23:10 -0500",
    image: "",
    last_event_date: null,
    name: "desk",
    thumbnail: "",
    type_of: "accessories"
  }
 ],
 events: [
  {
    id: 157,
    date: "2020-01-14 09:53:00 -0500",
    image: null,
    name: ""
  }
],
looks: [

],
tags: [
  {
    id: 97,
    created_at: "2020-01-20 10:46:12 -0500",
    title: "greatest person"
  }
]
 }
}
```

I want to parse each object to become a SearchResult POJO, with those field, `id`, `title` (which is either name or title from json), and `type` which is the object key, like clothing_items, events...

Comment: Crate data model class and parse it.    Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
  Staff staff = gson.fromJson(json, Staff.class);

Answer (score 0):

Crate data model class and parse it. Here Staff is the data model class contain name filed.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(json, Staff.class);
```